# UIImage reduce byte size

Tags: iphone, objective-c, resize, uiimage, reduce

I am using following code to resize an image - it all works well and as expected...

[Resize UIImage the right way](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/)

I use interpolation quality as `kCGInterpolationLow` and `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,0.0)` to get the `NSData` of that image.

The problem is that the image size is still a bit high in size at around 100kb. 
My question is can I reduce it further?

The images originate from the iPhone Photo Album and are selected via a `imagePickerController`.

Many thanks,

Comment: What is the resolution that you are resizing to?

Comment: As a test I created a dummy image in photoshop - if I selected the 'large file' option it was still only 21kb rather then the 100kb I am getting after resizing.

Comment: I cannot see a way of finding out (or overriding) Pixels/inch for an image selected from the photo album.

Comment: Below is the relevant code...

CGSize imgSize;
imgSize.width = 256.0;
imgSize.height = 280.0;

photo.image = [selectedImage resizedImageWithContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill bounds:imgSize interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationLow];

I have tried using different content modes that this does not seem to be the problem.

Comment: I tried your code with a sample image, but output is 8kb, can you somehow send your source image?

Comment: Firstly - many thanks for your help but I am beginning to think it is my original image (as directed by you!) - I think it was possibly already compressed or something.

Although I have now tried an orginal photo from my iPhone camera (sized 1.1MB - 2048x1536) -  the code (set on the lowest possible kCGInterpolationLow/UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,0.0) resized to 256x280) produced a file sized 90kb which although is a lot smaller is still quite big.

Comment: As a test - I took the same 1.1mb file and saved it in the largest jpg format in photoshop and it produced a file size 81kb and the lowest format produced a file sized 24kb.
I was hoping the get my file down to about 24kb as the photos are used in a page control/uiscrollview and need to be as small as possible but I beginning to think that 90kb ish is the lowest I can go.