# Reduce image size till given value ios

Tags: ios, image, core-data, image-processing, resize

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"anyImage.png"];

NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.032);

UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

I found this size reduction of image but my problem is that i need to store only 100kb of images. In my library i have 8159064kb of image which reduce upto 141258kb by this method. Please tell me a way to reduce size of image upto 100kb whatever size come it convert it to 100kb.
                                                               Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. Are you asking how to compress 8 gigs of images to 100 kilobytes? If so, 100KB each or total?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013871/uiimage-reduce-byte-size If that is not really 8kk Kb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should resize the `image.size` so it can reduce your large image to 100k

You can make a `UIImage` category

like `UIImage(Resize)`

```
+(UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image andWidth:(CGFloat)width andHeight:(CGFloat)height
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( CGSizeMake(width, height));
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,width,height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

And then make a `while` loop to resize the image size to fit for <= 100KB

```
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(_yourImage);
while (data.length / 1000 >= 100) {
    _yourImage = [UIImage imageWithImage:_yourImage andWidth:image.size.width/2 andHeight:image.size.height/2];
    data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(_yourImage);
}

// _yourImage is now reduce the size which is <= 100KB
```

Comment: While it might work, you are better to use `CGBitmapContextCreate` when resizing, check [this article](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/).